# get rows where n of m values are wrong answered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
right_answer   rater1   rater2   rater3   item
1              1        1        2        S01
1              1        2        2        S02
2              1        2        1        S03
2              2        1        2        S04
```

and I need to get those rows or values in 'items' where at least two out of the three raters gave the wrong answer. I could already check if all the raters agree with each other with this code:

```
df.where(df[['rater1', 'rater2', 'rater3']].eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).all(1) == True)
```

I don't want to calculate a column with a majority voting because maybe I need to adjust the number of raters that have to agree or disagree wih the right answer.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the dataframe containing columns like `rater`, then use [`DataFrame.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) along `axis=0` to compare the columns containing `rater` with the column `right_answer`, then use [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) along `axis=1` to get number of `raters` who have given wrong answer, then use [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) to create a boolean mask, finally filter the dataframe rows using this `mask`:

```
mask = (
    df.filter(like='rater')
    .ne(df['right_answer'], axis=0).sum(axis=1).ge(2)
)

df = df[mask]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

   right_answer  rater1  rater2  rater3 item
1             1       1       2       2  S02
2             2       1       2       1  S03
```

Answer (score 3):

For speed up, purely using [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
diffs = np.not_equal(df.filter(like='rater'), df['right_answer'][:, None])
diffs = np.sum(diffs, axis=1) >= 2

df[diffs]

   right_answer  rater1  rater2  rater3 item
1             1       1       2       2  S02
2             2       1       2       1  S03
```

---

**Lets time it!**

```
# create dataframe with 4 million rows
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*1000000, ignore_index=True)
dfbig.shape

# (4000000, 5)
```

```
def numpy_broadcasting(data):
    diffs = np.not_equal(data.filter(like='rater'), data['right_answer'][:, None])
    diffs = np.sum(diffs, axis=1) >= 2


def pandas_method(data):
    mask = (
    data.filter(like='rater')
    .ne(df['right_answer'], axis=0).sum(axis=1).ge(2)
    )

%%timeit
numpy_broadcasting(dfbig)
# 92.5 ms ± 789 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
pandas_method(dfbig)
# 296 ms ± 7.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`numpy broadcasting` is `296 / 92.5 = 3.2` times faster